# Need suggestions to get a unique index keys for two or more tables on mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, auto-increment

Usually, I use auto_increment attribute to get an unique key/id for each row on a single table to use as a primary index. Now I have two tables and unfortunately auto_increment can't create a new key using the last id/key on another table to keep all the keys/id unique in both. If I'll use auto_increment on both index columns, the possibility to have two identical ID is assured! There is a easy way to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Sounds like a database design that could be optimized...

Comment: Maybe, I'll try to explain the issue better. Those two tables contain two type of "insertion" into a main document, one is binary and one textual. When the sw routine show all the document, it retrieve this one from the "document table" and, after that, all the insertion from the two tables. After the join query the only mode to know what insertion is, is its id/key. There is no way to know form what table the insertion came, unless I put another id to distinguish binary from textual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least from a perspective of relational database design, your requirement seems unsound.  You ought to create a separate table with the common auto_increment field and point to that from the other two tables with foreign keys.

Answer (score 2):

If you have:

- table A with ids 1,2,3.
- table B with ids 1,2,3.

Then you already have the following (virtual) unique identifiers:

- A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3

You don't need to make any changes to your database. This is purely a presentation issue.

Comment: I separate in two tables only for the different data contents. I start thinking that it wasn't a good idea.